# MATCH for nodes with variable label name NEO4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, cypher-3.1

By queries in neo4j I get name of label as variable so in the same query I want to find all nodes with this label. I know that I can't have variable for label name like this

```
MATCH (n:${variable}) RETURN n
```

and nor

```
MATCH (n:variable) RETURN n
```

I am looking for work around for my situation I couldn't find `apoc` function for this situation. I expected a function like this

```
apoc.match.node(['labelName'])
```

I know that it's possible to find nodes with label using `WHERE`

```
WHERE label IN labels(nodes)
```

My guess is that this structure will slow down the speed of search so I want to avoid it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with pure Cypher but you can consider using APOC's `apoc.cypher.run` procedure :

```
WITH $variable AS label
CALL apoc.cypher.run("MATCH (:" + label + ") RETURN count(*) AS count", {})
YIELD value
RETURN label, value.count AS count;
```

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.cypher/apoc.cypher.run/#usage-apoc.cypher.run

Comment: This is not secured against injections!